# click() vs. live() vs. onclick (many divs) in jQuery 

Tags: click, onclick, jquery

I have a list with 200 divs,

```
<div id="sId_1" class="sDiv"></div>
<div id="sId_2" class="sDiv"></div>
....
<div id="sId_200" class="sDiv"></div>.
```

What of the following two is faster?

```
-- each loop -- with i++;
    <div onclick="callSomeFunction('click');" id="sId_'+i+'" ></div> 
-- each loop --


-- each loop -- with i++;
    $('#sId_'+i+'').click( function (event) ....
-- each loop --


$('.sDiv').click( function (event) ......
```

Is it the first solution? Because jQuery creates an object in the $.cache for every div.

PS: is an object with more than 1000 entries a problem for JavaScript?

Comment: http://www.jsperf.com might be a good place to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use event delegation to attach a single "smart" event handler to a suitable parent container:

```
$("#parent").delegate("div[id^='sId']", "click", function() {
    // do something
});
```

Advantages of the above approach:

- Only one event handler.
- Can be attached to a jQuery object as opposed to a selector, which
  makes `.delegate` calls chainable.
- Works for future elements, such as those added via JS/Ajax.
- You can stop the propagation/bubbling of events since they only bubble up to the parent and not the `document` element as is the case with `.live`.

Reference:

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Nice, never quite understood the advantage of delegate over live until now.

Answer (score 1):

The first is the fastest, but it will cost you with size page.

The second need to be fixed, because you will not do this to 100 divs.

So you can make each div a class which you will then call like this:

```
$(".divPRessable").click( ...
```

The last is only faster if you going to inject divs to DOM (slowest).

Comment: You've got me wrong. ... i updated my posting. Thanks for the fast answer.